# Unexpected RuntimeException from tika

Tags: java, apache, parsing, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract the content of a large dataset that contains a mix of files (`pdf`, `doc`, `ppt`).

I'm using `tika-app-1.12.jar`, when T run my code everything done perfectly then I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException:
Unexpected RuntimeException from
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@3ea25501  at
org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:258)
        at
org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
        at
org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
        at
recruitmentprototyp.RecruitmentPrototyp.tikareadDoc(RecruitmentPrototyp.java:135)
        at
recruitmentprototyp.RecruitmentPrototyp.doForAll(RecruitmentPrototyp.java:110)
        at
recruitmentprototyp.RecruitmentPrototyp.main(RecruitmentPrototyp.java:897)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pap style 19 claimed to
have itself as its parent, which isn't allowed  at
org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.StyleSheet.createPap(StyleSheet.java:232)
        at org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:120)
        at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:346)       at
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:81)
        at
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:201)
        at
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:172)
        at
org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
        ... 5 more Java Result: 1
```

what should I do?!!

Comment: Report an issue to Tika library?

Comment: No I didn't report it

Comment: Skip that partly corrupted document, and proceed with your other files?

Comment: I did this after reading your answer.. I modified my code to know where the code has stopped and I removed that file and rerun my code and this exception appear once again in a file that extracted before without any problems

Comment: @Gagravarr I divided my dataset to 2 parts and it's worked well... I don't know if the number of doc have a role in this context

Comment: It's that one specific file you need to skip, not anything else. Apache Tika has support for logging failures but carrying on, look at `Tika Batch` for details

Comment: thanx @Gagravarr I will read more about it :)

Comment: @abeerzaroor is this question solved I have the same issue